# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' Entity Framework Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with Entity Framework 4.4 to a shared web hosting (GoDaddy-4GH platform). In GoDaddy I can't create databases using the application code I have to create it via their control panel, which I did.

I want to use the migration feature to allow my database to evolve without manually modify the schema.

I've use a combination of `IDatabaseInitializer` and `DbMigrationsConfiguration`. The db initializer simply migrates to the latest version.

The problem is that during the update process EF checks whether the database exists using the `EnsureDatabaseExists` method, and if for some reason it decides that is does not, then it goes ahead and tries to create a new database which of course fails.

1. How can I debug why the `EnsureDatabaseExists` returns false?
2. Is it possible to override this behavior? (from looking at the code with reflection it does not seem that way)

`DBMigration` implementation

```
public class DBMigrationInitializaer : IDatabaseInitializer<AppDbContext> {

public void InitializeDatabase(AppDbContext context) {
  bool dbExists;
  var mig = new DbMigrator(new MigrationConfiguration());
  mig.Update();

  Seed(context);
  context.SaveChanges();
}

protected virtual void Seed(AppDbContext context) {
  // TODO: put here your seed creation
}
```

Exception stack trace

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2072894
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5061932
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) +228
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +326
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClassa.<DbCreateDatabase>b__7(SqlConnection conn) +38
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +98
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +349
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +315
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +73
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +44
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +12
   MvcApplication1.Models.MyDBInitializaer.InitializeDatabase(AppContext context) in MyDBInitializaer.cs:31
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +19
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +186
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +190
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   MvcApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeController.Index() in EmployeeController.cs:21
```

Thank you,
Ido

Comment: You should not need to use custom initializer. Did you configure your connection string correctly?

Comment: The result were exactly the same when I use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion derived class. The connection string is correct, when it is not I get a different error message

Comment: Can you test if your application can execute queries against master database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with my webhost (**amen.fr**). During **SEVERAL** days I looked and I realized that there's something in the implementation of the class DBMigrator and sql server configuring at the host which causes this dysfunction. "**System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists**" unable to check the correct information. That why all transactions with the database are made with my data context. Here is the code that allows me to make semi-automatic migration :

```
public class Migrator
  {
    public static void RunMigrations()
    {
      //Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

      //configuration.ContextType = typeof(BOContext);//TODO Change to your DbContext
      //configuration.MigrationsAssembly = configuration.ContextType.Assembly;
      //configuration.MigrationsNamespace = "BO.Domain.Migrations";//TODO Namespace that contains your migrations classes
      //configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");

      //DbSeederMigrator<BOContext> migrator = new DbSeederMigrator<BOContext>(configuration);
      //migrator.MigrateToLatestVersion();

      using (BOContext context = new BOContext())
      {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.ContextType = typeof(BOContext);//TODO Change to your DbContext
        configuration.MigrationsAssembly = configuration.ContextType.Assembly;
        configuration.MigrationsNamespace = "CodeFirstMembershipSharp.Migrations";//TODO Namespace that contains your migrations classes
        configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");

        DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        MigratorScriptingDecorator scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);

        var lm = migrator.GetLocalMigrations();// get local migration
        var dm = context.Database.SqlQuery<Migration>("select MigrationId from dbo.__MigrationHistory").Select(o => o.MigrationId); // get database migration
        List<string> pm = lm.Except(dm).ToList();// buil and set pending migration

        if (pm.Any())// Peding migration exists
        {
          string source = dm.Any() ? dm.OrderBy(o => o).Last() : DbMigrator.InitialDatabase;// get last to set source migration
          string target = pm.OrderBy(o => o).Last(); /// gest last to set target migration

          string sql = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(source, target); // buit sql script migration

          try { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql); } // execute sql script migration
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            string spm = "Pending migrations : " + String.Join(";", pm.ToArray());
            string sdm = "Database migrations : " + String.Join(";", pm.ToArray());
            string[] tmp = { e.Message, spm, sdm, "Source : " + source, "Target : " + target, sql };

            throw new Exception(String.Join("\n-----------------\n", tmp));
          }
        }
      }

      //// TODO : code seed here
      //Migrator.Seed();
    }

    protected static void Seed()
    {
      //using (BOContext context = new BOContext())
      //{
      //  if (!context.Users.Any())
      //  {
      //    MembershipCreateStatus Status;
      //    Membership.CreateUser("Demo", "123456", "demo@demo.com", null, null, true, out Status);

      //    if (!context.Roles.Any(o => o.RoleName == "Admin"))
      //    {
      //      Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
      //      Roles.AddUserToRole("Demo", "Admin");
      //    }
      //  }
      //}
    }laguna-veneta
  }
```

Comment: You rewrite Migrator class if I understand this right? I guess it's the only available solution for now because EnsureDatabaseExist method is internal and does not allow the be override.

Comment: I've move my hosting service from GoDaddy to DiscountASP. They are more expensive but everything seem to work there. Thank you for sharing the code.