# EntityFramework migrations tries to create an existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We're deploying a simple ASP.NET MVC application to on of our staging servers and we're getting the following error when EntityFramework tries to migrate the existing database.

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

The situation is as follows:

- This is the first time the migrations run.
- The database already exists (it's actually an Umbraco database).

It would appear the the following method (from EntityFramework) returns false, when it obviously should return true:

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists()
```

The database initializer has the following code:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
```

Automatic migrations is turned off, because we're using Code-Based migrations.

The connectionstring points to the correct database and the user has db_owner rights on that database. The user has no rights to other tables on the server.

Is this a common problem? Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thnx!

Comment: could you try setting it to not be master as that's the name of a system database and could cause issues

Comment: possible duplicate of [CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' Entity Framework Migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814762/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-entity-framework-migratio)

Comment: The database name in the connectionstring isn't master (as this is indeed a system database). It's an existing database and the user only has rights to that db. EntityFramework tries to create the database because the EnsureDatabaseExists reports that there is no database. After that EF tries to create the DB, but the user has no rights for that. That, however, is not the problem. EF fails to detect that the db actually exists for some reason

Comment: As mentioned in linked question it may be subsequent problem. The account must have permission to query master database to check if your database exists.

Comment: It may be that EF needs to create a temporary db to do the migrations. Can you give it sa privs and watch with SQL profiler what it does?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure database exists - executes the following script

```
IF db_id(N'MyDatabaseName') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'MyDatabaseName'
```

that assumes users permission to query `'sys.databases'`for a list of DB's.
If this query fails - EF thinks that DB has NOT been created and tries to create it again.

Make sure - that the user executing the migration, is able to execute the query above successfully

Comment: Useful, but how did you figure this out? And secondly - can we get EF to stop doing that, it's not appropriate for a secure environment :)

Comment: figuring this out - hm.. used a piece of SQL from standard SQL database create script, that SSMS generates. And how can we stop EF from trying to create a database ? I think yes. Just create a custom DB initializer instead of relying on the default implementation that comes out of the box